# Suppose $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$. Prove that $G/H \times G/K$ has a subgroup that is isomorphic to $G / (H∩K)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

> Suppose $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$. Prove that $G/H \times G/K$ has a subgroup that is isomorphic to $G / (H∩K)$.
>
> Also prove  that if $G = HK$, then $G/(H∩K)$ is isomorphic to $G/H \times G/K$

So far I have that by the second isomorphism theorem, $H/(H ∩ K)$ is isomorphic to $HK/K$. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You should review the proofs of the isomorphism theorems. They will give you the insight you need to solve these problems.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: there is a natural homomorphism
$$
\varphi\colon G\to G/H\times G/K
$$
defined by $\varphi(x)=(xH,xK)$. What's its kernel? What's its image in case $HK=G$?

Answer (score 2):

Define

$$\phi: G\to G/H\times G/K\;,\;\;\phi x:=(xH,\,xK)$$

Prove the above is a group homomorphism and show $\;\ker\phi=H\cap K\;$ . Finally, use the first isomorphism theorem.

If you understand the above then the second part should be easier.

Comment: For the second part, I started with: define φ: HK →G/H×G/K by φ(hk)=(xH, xK). I then went through with proving it was a homomorphism... am I on the right track to proving G/(H∩K) is isomorphic to G/H×G/K? or am I missing an easier way to do it with the isomorphism theorems?

Comment: @KatieMediate Use the very same map for the 2nd part, and use that $\;G=HK\;$ ... **BUT** you almost should use that $\;HK=KH\;$ since this is a sufficient and necessary condition for the product of two subgroups to be a subgroup again. With this you shouldn't have tough problems to show the map *now* is surjective.